# Why does "flatMap" work with sequences of Option type in Scala?

Tags: scala, option-type, flatmap

I can't figure out how the Scala compiler figures out how to use `flatMap` with a sequence of `Option`s.

If I use a `flatMap` on a sequence of sequences:

```
println(Seq(Seq(1), Seq()).flatMap(a => a)) // List(1)
```

it will concatenate all nested sequences

The same happens if I use it with a sequence of `Option`s:

```
println(Seq(Some(1), None).flatMap(a => a)) // List(1)
```

So the `flatMap` treats `Option` as a collection in this case. The question is why does this work? The `flatMap` has the following definition:

```
def flatMap[B, That](f: A => GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That
```

Meaning that it expects a function that returns an instance of `GenTraversableOnce`, but `Option` does not inherit `GenTraversableOnce`. It only inherits `Product` and `Serializable`, and `Product` inherits `Equals`.

How does Scala compiler can use the `flatMap` on the sequence of `Option`s in this case?

Comment: To add to Grzegorzs answer, this also arises from the fact `Option[A]` is a *monad*, although this is blurred out due to the generic signature on options flatmap. The `flatMap` (otherwise named `bind`) on `Option[A]` should really be: `def flatMap(f: A => Option[B]): Option[B]`, which is what you see in functional libraries such as scalaz and cats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your observation is right. In this case, if the compiler can't match the type, it looks for an implicit conversion and finds one in `Option`'s companion object:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

/** 
    An implicit conversion that converts an option to an iterable value
*/

implicit def option2Iterable[A](xo: Option[A]): Iterable[A] = xo.toList
```

This makes it possible to treat `Option`s as `Iterable`s.

---

Also, your code can be simplified using `flatten`:

```
Seq(Some(1), None).flatten
```